# Access JavaScript map similarly to plain object

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary

I am using Map

because I want to store an object as a key.

My question is - can I access a map the same way I would access a plain object?

For example:

```
let m = new Map();
let obj = {foo:'bar'};
m[obj] = 'baz';
console.log(m[obj]);
```

is this supposed to work correctly as is, or do I need to use the get/set methods of a Map?

The reason I ask is because if I need to use get/set it forces to me to carefully refactor a lot of code.

Here is a real life example of code that may need to be refactored:

*// before (broker.wsLock was plain object)*

```
function addWsLockKey(broker, ws, key) {
  let v;
  if (!( v = broker.wsLock[ws])) {
    v = broker.wsLock[ws] = [];
  }
  if (v.indexOf(key) < 0) {
    v.push(key);
  }
}
```

*// after (broker.wsLock is a Map instance)*

```
function addWsLockKey(broker, ws, key) {
  let v;
  if (!( v = broker.wsLock.get(ws))) {
    v = [];
    broker.wsLock.set(ws, v);
  }
  if (v.indexOf(key) < 0) {
    v.push(key);
  }
}
```

is there some way to set v on the same line as the set() call?

Comment: a Map is just like any other JS object, so you can add properties like you are doing, however, what you are doing is adding a property `"[object Object]"` - rather than adding an actual map entry. in other words, you need to use set/get

Comment: I just tried your example in the console - it seems to work fine.

Comment: @Zac, it only appears to work, the value is not actually assigned to a property represented by the actual object, instead gets set to a property named `[object Object]` as Jaromanda X mentions.

Comment: Use `m.set(obj, 'baz'); console.log(m.get(obj));`

Comment: yeah, I am looking for a definitive answer to this, using bracket notation can be really convenient, let me update the question with a better example.

Comment: according jfriend00, yeah you have to use get/set to get the real Map functionality, see his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want access to the actual values of the `Map` object, then you have to use `.get()` and `.set()` or various iterators.

```
var m = new Map();
m.set("test", "foo");
console.log(m.get("test"));    // "foo"
```

Regular property access on a `Map`  such as:

```
m["test"] = "foo"
```

just sets a regular property on the object - it does not affect the actual map data structure.

I imagine it was done this way so that you can access the `Map` object properties separately from the members of the `Map` data structure and the two shall not be confused with one another.

---

In addition, regular properties will only accept a string as the property name so you can't use a regular property to index an object.  But, map objects have that capability when using `.set()` and `.get()`.

---

You asked for a "definitive" answer to this.  In the [ES6 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-map.prototype.set), you can look at what `.set()` does and see that it operates on the `[[MapData]]` internal slot which is certainly different than the properties of an object.  And, likewise, there is no where in that spec where it says that using normal property access would access the internal object `[[MapData]]`.  So, you'll have to just see that normal property access is describe for an Object.  A `Map` is an `Object` and there's nothing in the `Map` specification that says that normal property access should act any different than it does for any other object.  In fact, it has to act the same for all the methods on the `Map` object or they wouldn't work if you happened to put an item in the `Map` with the same key as a method name.  So, you're proof consists of this:

1. A simple test will show you that property access does not put anything in the `Map` itself, only a regular property.
2. The spec describes a `Map` as an object.
3. The spec describes how `.get()` and `.set()` operate on the internal slot `[[MapData]]`.
4. There's nothing in the spec that says property access on a `Map` object should work any different than it always does.
5. If property access did access the `MapData`, then you would not be able to access methods if you happened to put a key in the `Map` that conflicted with a method name - that would be a mess if that was the case.

Comment: Got it, that makes sense

Comment: Yeah the reason I need to use map is so that I can use an object as key. Thanks for the info.

Comment: However, I am looking for this kind of convenience:

Comment: let v = obj[x] = obj[x] || 'foo';

Comment: the above line of code is super convenient. Not sure it's possible with get/set of Map.

Comment: @Olegzandr - I've also found it a pain to handle default values for assigning to a map.  I typically ended up using a helper function or a subclass of map that has new versions of  `.set()` that handles default values for you.  In my case, it was when I had a map of arrays and I need to either add an item to the existing array or initialize a new array, but it's the same type of issue.   Just make yourself some helper functions or a subclass of `Map` with some new methods that do what you want.

Comment: there ain't nothing much like POJSOs...that's the #1 reason why the language is so nice to work with. And why JSON is a thing.